# Split groups in a data frame and re-aggregate

Tags: r, pivot, aggregate

I have this data frame,

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c(
    'Oxidation (M)',
    'Unmodified',
    'Acetyl (Protein N−term)',
    'Acetyl (Protein N−term);Oxidation (M)',
    'Unmodified;Acetyl (Protein N−term)'
  ),
  freq = c(10,5,6,3,1)
)
```

| group | freq |
| --- | --- |
| Oxidation (M) | 10 |
| Unmodified | 5 |
| Acetyl (Protein N−term) | 6 |
| Acetyl (Protein N−term);Oxidation (M) | 3 |
| Unmodified;Acetyl (Protein N−term) | 1 |

The last two rows are composed of groups that are already present and **always** separated by `;`

I would like to further split those groups, and reaggregate their `freq` resulting in this:

```
df_expected <- data.frame(
  group = c(
    'Oxidation (M)', 
    'Unmodified',
    'Acetyl (Protein N−term)'
  ),
  freq = c(13, 6, 10)
)
```

| group | freq |
| --- | --- |
| Oxidation (M) | 13 |
| Unmodified | 6 |
| Acetyl (Protein N−term) | 10 |

I have been trying to use aggregate, but with no success so far.

Comment: You put a lot of work in making a good problem statement, but no example of your effort so far. - either way the answer was given and probably doesn't need the downvotes anymore as both combine into a useful posting.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm new to StackOverflow and indeed I did not understand the downvotes. I will take that into account the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% separate_rows(group, sep = ';') %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(freq = sum(freq))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  group                    freq
  <chr>                   <dbl>
1 Acetyl (Protein N-term)    10
2 Oxidation (M)              13
3 Unmodified                  6
```

Comment: It does, that separate_rows function is what I needed, thanks!